# Angular - Verify FormControl has Validator failing in unit test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs

I am writing unit tests for a service that receives a FormControl and options specify which Validators should be added and then returned.

My unit test should validate that the FormControl has the required, minLength and maxLength validators, however, it always fails checking that the min or max length validator exists.

When debugging i can verify that it has 3 validators in its array.

For brevity, i've just written it in one test function:

```
  it('should create input form field validators', () => {
    const control = new FormControl<string>(
      '',
      [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(1),
        Validators.maxLength(9)
      ]
    );

    expect(control.hasValidator(Validators.required)).toBeTruthy();

    // the next two lines should pass as true, but both fail.
    expect(control.hasValidator(Validators.minLength(1))).toBeTruthy();
    expect(control.hasValidator(Validators.maxLength(9))).toBeTruthy()
  });
```

This should be very straight forward. Is there something I am missing here? Why is the logic for Required passing, but the others fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a reference issue:

Example Code from Angular docs:
https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#reference-to-a-validatorfn-1

```
// Reference to the RequiredValidator
const ctrl = new FormControl<number | null>(0, Validators.required);
expect(ctrl.hasValidator(Validators.required)).toEqual(true)

// Reference to anonymous function inside MinValidator
const minValidator = Validators.min(3);
const ctrl = new FormControl<number | null>(0, minValidator);
expect(ctrl.hasValidator(minValidator)).toEqual(true)
expect(ctrl.hasValidator(Validators.min(3))).toEqual(false)
```

So your code should look like that:

```
it('should create input form field validators', () => {
  const minValidator = Validators.minLength(1);
  const maxValidator = Validators.maxLength(9);

  const control = new FormControl<string>('', [Validators.required, minValidator, maxValidator]);

  expect(control.hasValidator(Validators.required)).toBeTruthy();
  expect(control.hasValidator(minValidator)).toBeTruthy();
  expect(control.hasValidator(maxValidator)).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Comment: I just saw that myself in the docs. Unfortunately, I have written a "factory" service that takes an AbstractFormControl and an interface that defines which validators and their values should be added, so I do not have access to the exact validator defined in order to use the hasValidator function. 

I have changed direction to instead setting the control value to trigger the error messages and validating functionality through them.

Comment: @CodyPritchard Can you provide a stackblitz?

Comment: I added an answer that explains my implementation and the solution I had to use.

Answer (score 0):

As Schrader answered, the problem was a constructor/reference issue due to how I have created my services.

I have a factory service that I can reuse to create and add validators to FormControls, like so:

```
  private buildForm(): FormGroup {
    return new FormGroup({
      myControl: this.formControlFactory.buildFormControl(myControlInterface),
      ...
    });
  }
```

The FormControlFactory service is like so:

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class FormControlValidatorFactory {

  buildFormControl(formField: IInputFormField): FormControl {
    const control = new FormControl<string>('');
    if (formField.validators?.required) this.getRequiredValidator(control);
    if (formField.validators?.length) this.getLengthValidators(control, formField);
    if (formField.validators?.number) this.getNumberValidators(control, formField);
    if (formField.validators?.pattern) this.getPatternValidator(control, formField);
    return control;
  }

  ...

  private getLengthValidators(control: FormControl, formField: IInputFormField): void {
    if (formField.validatorValues?.minLength) 
      control.addValidators(Validators.minLength(formField.validatorValues.minLength));
    
    if (formField.validatorValues?.maxLength) 
      control.addValidators(Validators.maxLength(formField.validatorValues.maxLength));
  }
  ...
}
```

The methods in this service look at the interface and add validators based on boolean values, so, in the unit tests, I do not have access to the actual validators that were added and I must test the service functionality a different way.

In order to verify that the correct validators were added, I opted to unit test like so:

```
  it('should have minLength validator and error', () => {
    inputFormField.validators = { length: true };
    inputFormField.validatorValues = { minLength: 3 };
    inputControl = service.buildFormControl(inputFormField);

    inputControl.setValue('x');
    const errors = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(inputControl.errors));

    expect(inputControl.invalid).toEqual(true);
    expect(errors.minlength).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

Writing a similar unit test for each validator scenario until I have complete coverage.